# Позиционирование внутри элемента

Tags: html, css

К примеру у меня есть такое изображение, в него я поместил текст, как мне теперь в этой картинке к примеру переместить название загрузка в правый нижний угол?

```css
* {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #fff;
}

.images-background {
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}

.upload {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

img {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-background">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566762492169-816dfd8be4b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
  <div class="upload">Загрузить</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Используйте свойства `top, right, left, bottom`

Comment: Пример изменил немного для наглядности.

Comment: Для чего у  элемента `.upload ` правило `justify-content: flex-end;` Это правило для `Flex-контейнера`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положение элемента задается свойствами left, top, right и bottom, также на положение влияет значение свойства position родительского элемента. Так, если у родителя значение position установлено как static или родителя нет, то отсчет координат ведется от края окна браузера. Если у родителя значение position задано как fixed, relative или absolute, то отсчет координат ведется от края родительского элемента.

```css
.images-background {
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
  width:1330px;
  height:900px;
  background-image:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566762492169-816dfd8be4b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
}

.upload {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-background">
  <div class="upload">Загрузить</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Название уходит в правый угол экрана, а как его разместить именно в правом углу картинки?

Comment: @Артем для картинки задать `position: relative`

Comment: @Alpha Вот выше пример который привел там оно используется, но текст все равно ушел за границы

Comment: Обновил, проблема была в том что img был реализован как отдельный элемент, соответственно position relative работал и для картинки и для текста. Для твоей задачи лучше подойдет background-image.

Comment: @Daniell0 Подскажите, добавил к себе на сайт, теперь картинка не отображается, в чем проблема?  https://codepen.io/sport_defense/pen/JjPWLEZ

Comment: У тебя не хватает полей width и height для блока .background-profile-images

Comment: @Daniell0 Спасибо за помощь! Сегодня день у меня не из легких, на таком моменте застопорился)

Comment: @Артем Без проблем, у самого такое бывает;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.images-background {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.upload {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-background">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566762492169-816dfd8be4b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
  <div class="upload">Загрузить</div>
</div>
```